# soapui read from excel with DataSource and DataLoop more rows then in my excel file

Tags: excel, groovy, datasource, soapui

i read from excel with DataSource and DataLoop more rows then  in my excel file.
Between  there is Groovy script that feel one property in the TestSuite

Script:

```
def stringD = ''

def readD = context.expand( '${readD#Users}' )  //excel

def users = context.expand( '${#TestSuite#Users}' )

log.info(readD)
        if(users=='')

        { stringD = users + readD
                }

        else
        {

            stringD = users +','+ readD

        }

 testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue( "Users", stringD )
```

In Property(#TestSuite#Users) i see all users and in end yet same count komas(,)(Property not need them)

Excel:

Users

1

2

3

3-steps dataSource, Script, DataLoop

Step Script - take each value and add to property (script attach before)

The property get :  1,2,3,,,

(with 3 ',' in the end)

Comment: I don't understand the question...  WHat is `users`? A list of usernames?  And you want a comma separated String of usernames?

Comment: yes users its data from excel file 
there is 10 rows but i get 10 elements in string and yet 10 ','

Comment: You're going to have to explain more in the question.. Maybe put examples of what you have in there (after every line?), and an example of what you want?

Comment: In your excel, go to the last row that has data and delete all rows after it. Save the excel and try again. This happens when you add or remove rows in the middle of existing rows.

Comment: @ Abhishek Asthana 
thank you. But file has only one column and one worksheet

Comment: @user3346475 that's all right. in that worksheet itself..go to the last cell in the column and delete all rows after it. Also, can you just do a log.info and print what all values? I want to see what all is being read from the excel.